# GetDlgItemText and Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc

So I have been trying to implement the concept of multithreading to an MFC application I am making. I used the method suggested [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2459/Using-AfxBeginThread-with-class-member-controlling). It works fine but I am having an issue with using data given by the user while the thread is working.

I'll explain.

I am making a simple GUI to send and receive data over a serial port. So the data in IDC_SEND is user-input, and is then sent through the serial port. I am using the WINAPI definition of GetDlgItemText, but since the controlling function for AfxBeginThread is defined as a static function I cannot do this. So I tried ::GetDlgItemText, but that calls the CWnd definition which takes one or three or four(?) arguments.

So ::GetDlgItemText(IDC_SEND, CString text) doesn't work. This problem continues for SetDlgItemText too.

I have tried getting the data outside my controlling function, but since it is defined to return a UINT type, I cannot get the received data out.

The relevant code

```
void CCommTest2Dlg::OnButton() 
{   
THREADSTRUCT *_param = new THREADSTRUCT;
_param->_this = this;
AfxBeginThread (StartThread, _param);
}


UINT CCommTest2Dlg::StartThread(LPVOID param)
{
THREADSTRUCT*    ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)param;
AfxMessageBox ("Thread is started!");

//Opened Serial Port

//Writing data from Editbox
CString text;

::GetDlgItemText(IDC_SEND,text);//********ERROR HERE!!
serial.Write(text);

//At Receiver port data is wriiten into CString a.

CString a;

::SetDlgItemText( IDC_RECV, a);//Apparently this calls the SetDlgItemText from the CWnd class, and not the Windows API that takes more than one argument.
AfxMessageBox ((LPCTSTR)a);//This works, but I need the data in the EditBox.

//Closing Ports 

delete ts; //Edit 1
return 1;}
```

A few definitions:

```
static UINT StartThread (LPVOID param);

//structure for passing to the controlling function
typedef struct THREADSTRUCT
       {
          CCommTest2Dlg*    _this;

        } THREADSTRUCT;

UINT StartThread(void);
```

Any thoughts?

PS: Also Edit 1 at the end was added by me as I read that this implementation could result in memory leaks. Does it look like the addition might have fixed that?

Comment: You should retrieve dialog item text to be send at `OnButton` handler and pass it to your thread as parameter (right now you are passing `THREADSTRUCT` instance but do not even use it).

Comment: @VTT I changed the code accordignly to:                                          
void CCommTest2Dlg::OnButton() 
{       CString text;
 GetDlgItemText(IDC_SEND,text);
 AfxBeginThread (StartThread,text);
}   Now I get this : error C2665: 'AfxBeginThread' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: This error informs you that you are trying to call a function with arguments that it does not accept. Please look up what arguments `AfxBeginThread` expects and compare them with what you are using.

Comment: You are calling the free function [GetDlgItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645489.aspx), but passing arguments compatible with the class member [CWnd::GetDlgItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcws9sbs(v=vs.120).aspx). Besides, accessing GUI controls across threads without **any** synchronization isn't going to end well.